# JavaScript error in function which calcs sum of two values

Tags: javascript, php

this is my JS code to check the match of two digits

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function match(){
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one"));
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two"));
var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("sum"));
var d;
d=a+b;
if(d!=c)
    {
    alert("Something is wrong!!");
    }
    else
        {
            alert ("Success");

        }

}
</script>
```

html code for generat two digits and check on the process.

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return match();">
<input type="text"  name="one" id="one" value="<?php echo rand(1,9); ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
+
<input type="text" name="two" id="two" value="<?php echo rand(1,9); ?>" readonly="readonly"/>
=
<input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: here : http://jsfiddle.net/LM8fB/

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want their value and not the element itself.

```
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value,10);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("two").value,10);
var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("sum").value,10);
```

Also, provide the `radix` when you are using `parseInt()` otherwise it may go crazy sometimes.